# Update through Hibernate or Hql/Sql?

Tags: hibernate

I have a doubt regarding hiberate update. Suppose say i have a Student table in DB with properties as **studentId**(Primary Key), **lastName**, **firstName**(Not null) and **age**.  Now say i have to update ***lastName*** of a student with **studentId = 5**. If i do as below

```
HibernateTemplate ht = HibernteTemplate(getSessionFactory());
Student s = new Student();
s.setStudentId(5);
s.setLastName("Kevin");
ht.update(s);
```

This gives me error saying can't update as **firstName** can't be null.

Now if i do as below.

```
HibernateTemplate ht = HibernteTemplate(getSessionFactory());
Student s = ht.get(Student.class,5);  // 1st DB call    
s.setLastName("Kevin");
ht.update(s);  // 2nd DB call
```

So here there are 2 DB calls, instead if i would have used simple Query(sql/hql) i would have updated the table with single DB call.

```
update student set lastName ='Kevin' where studentId=5;
```

So is using Hql/Sql better then Hibernate (1 DB call V/S 2) if we perform such updates? Please advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not every decision must be taken based on performance. Most of the time, getting an entity by ID is so fast that getting and updating the entity doesn't cause any performance problem.

It also has several advantages over the query solution:

- easier to understand, less place for bugs
- safer: no risk of having a spelling mistake
- compatible with optimistic locking
- refactorable (if the name property is changed to lastName, for example)
- doesn't cause the potentially already loaded student to have a name that doesn't match with the name in the database: update queries bypass the session cache
- doesn't cause an invalidation of the second level cache

Note that

- HibernateTemplate shouldn't be used anymore, for years
- Calling update() is completely unnecessary if you work in a single transaction: Hibernate automatically flushes the changes made to the attached entities.

Comment: JB, thanks a lot for sharing these details. Yes, template is gone long back, but the app already uses it so continuing it for now, would try to replace it with contextual session some time later.